# Need help understanding Testing in Ruby/Rails using Minitest and Mocha

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing

I was wondering if someone could give a broad explanation (high level overview) of testing using Minitest and Mocha in Rails, and perhaps when to use which types of testing utilities.

I seem to be getting caught up not knowing when to use `mock` vs `stub`, `expects` vs `stubs`, and the order of operations when mocking and stubbing and knowing how to "break down" the functionality of code.

For an example (and yes, I understand I'm testing side effects, but in this case, I don't know what else to test):

Class to be tested:

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

class UploadJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :upload

  def perform(batch_id)
    Logger.new.time('upload.time') do
      Uploader.new(batch_id).upload_data
    end
  end
end
```

Initial test that didn't work:

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'test_helper'

class TestUploadJob < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test 'UploadJob > perform > it should start uploading' do
    Logger.stubs(:new).then.stubs(:time).with('upload.time').yields
    Uploader.expects(:new).with(1).then.expects(:upload_data)

    UploadJob.perform_now(1)
  end
```

End result test that works:

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'test_helper'

class TestUploadJob < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test 'UploadJob > perform > it should start uploading' do
    logger_stub = stub
    logger_stub.stubs(:time).with('upload.time').yields
    Logger.stubs(:new).returns(logger_stub)

    uploader_mock = mock
    uploader_mock.expects(:upload_data)
    Uploader.expects(:new).with(1).returns(uploader_mock)

    UploadJob.perform_now(1)
  end
```

To me, it felt more declarative in the first test to say the exact order things would be called in. In the second test, that works, first I'm stubbing or mocking a method call that comes *after* the call to `<CLASS>.new`.

What's a better way of thinking about this/approaching this problem of testing? Are there any good resources *specific to testing with Minitest and Mocha, NOT Rspec*, that would be suggested reads?

Thanks!

Comment: there are certainly books/tutorials out there about testing with Minitest/Mocha ... but in my experience, RSpec is more full-featured, if you have the choice I would advise to use it instead.

Comment: Good start: mock nothing.

Comment: @maxpleaner ya that’s what I figured 